# BaseAdapter recycling issue - Android

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have the following BaseAdapter, the problem is that I'm seeing an ImageView recycling issue, where Images are getting displayed in another ImageView the issue is happening only when scrolling fast, what am I doing wrong here?

Let me walk you through the logic of what I'm trying to do, I have two sets of groups, groups and users in the code, both are ArrayList.

Now this users.size() + groups.size() gives me the total count, and inside the getView I have to tell if this view belongs to a group or to user.

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
    count = users.size() + groups.size();


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView =  infalter.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.image.setImageResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);


        if (position < groups.size()) {
            //I'm in the group section so get me the group name 
            holder.name.setText(groups.get(position));
            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().beginConfig()...;
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        } else {
        //I'm in the user section so get me the user image
        //this is where the problem is happening
         imageLoader.displayImage( "file://" + users.get(position - groups.size()), holder.image);

        }

        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name;


    }


}
```

Comment: what issue are you exactly facing? are you seeing textview in the user section or images are not in place?

Comment: ImageView issue, images are not in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the issue is here:
`imageLoader.displayImage`  - is an Async function, and in edge cases a Task might load the image into a recycled ImageView.

You should try when recycling the view calling: `imageLoader.cancelDisplayTask` on the ImageView you are recycling.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of UIL lib that you are using, checkout this [comment](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/376#issuecomment-30872810)